# Не могу понять почему выдает JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

При компиляции данного кода:

```
import json

user1 = {
'user_Name1':"Maxim",
'Money1':100
}

user2 = {
'user_Name2':"Sasha",
'Money':101
}

users = []
users.append(user1)
users.append(user2)

f = open('BD.txt','a')
# f.write(str(users))

json.dump(users, f)

f2 = open('BD.txt','r')
json_storage = json.load(f2)

for i in json_storage:
    print("Name is:" + str(user1['user_Name1']))
    print("Money:"+ str(user1['Money1']))
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 23, in <module>
    json_storage = json.load(f2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, 
**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Пытался скомпилировать заменив некоторые строки на это:

```
f = open('BD.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
f2 = open('BD.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Но опять же выдает ошибку, но другую:

```
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 18, in <module>
    json.dump(users, f)
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите кодировку, заменив на это:

```
f = open('BD.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
f2 = open('BD.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

---

И я бы рекомендовал так писать:

```
import json

user1 = {
    'user_Name1': "Maxim",
    'Money1': 100
}

user2 = {
    'user_Name2': "Sasha",
    'Money': 101
}

users = []
users.append(user1)
users.append(user2)

with open('BD.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

with open('BD.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json_storage = json.load(f)

for i in json_storage:
    print("Name is:", user1['user_Name1'])
    print("Money:", user1['Money1'])
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "source_file.py", line 18, in <module>
        json.dump(users, f)
    OSError: [Errno 27] File too large

Comment: @SuNøt, какая-то ошибка у вас?

Comment: выдает другую ошибку.

Comment: @SuNøt, ну бывает такое с кодом... а ошибка то какая? :)

Comment: я же написал ошибку... :(

Comment: @SuNøt, вы наверное комментарий с кодом или удалили, или правили, вот и не увидел. Смотрите, ошибка "File too large". Я думаю тут понятно, что первичная ошибка была исправлена и тут вы столкнулись со второй. А сколько весит `BD.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка OSError выдаётся когда у вас запущен тот же сервер в двух местах.
У меня возникала ошибка когда я запускал сервер на vscode потом на Pycharm
не остонавливая процесс на vscode.